# Deleting first half of string in php

Tags: php

If there is a string with two prices combined like `10.994.99`, I want it to split it into two strings and then delete the first string so I end up with `4.99`. However, it has to be cut two characters after the first decimal because the first/second number could be in the 100s place instead of 10s.

Comment: can you provide more examples; i don't understand the 2nd sentence

Comment: How do you make the string in the first place?You could separate it by a comma then

Comment: some combination of the following probable: explode, substr, strlen perhaps a regular expression

Comment: Jason B understood it well. My title may have been lacking but I couldn't find a duplicate of this question, so I don't know why I was downvoted...

Comment: I assume the downvotes are because there was no code that demonstrates your attempts to solve the problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to find the substring that starts two characters after the first . which is found using str_pos()

```
$my_var = '10.994.99';

$my_price = substr( $my_var, strpos( $my_var, '.') + 3 );

echo $my_price; // 4.99
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc9daa316033836352178fb39785303a9e3bbdc8